# How to prove function differentiable at t0 is continuous in Norm?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

[For definition continuous and differentiable of function in Norm you can see here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O2wcMhMF6uLy48JRNMa0-8-qUKsGmVFv/view?usp=drivesdk)
I'm stuck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to make this a comment but I lack sufficient reputation.

An answer to your question might be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116602/prove-a-differentiable-function-between-banach-spaces-is-continuous/2116664#2116664).